# How to share a draw.io diagram to receive comments or feedback?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Students at my university use draw.io to create concept maps and I would like be able to tell them how to (easily) share their work with their teacher so the latter can provide feedback, grade it etc. The students would preferably use Google Drive as we use Google Apps for Education.

At the moment It's not very important *how* the teacher would provide feedback, I'd already be happy with a comments box or some extra text above or below the students' diagram.

**Things I've tested so far:** I created a diagram and shared it with myself on a different account and with both the "Can comment" and "can edit" option of Google Drive sharing, I wasn't able to provide feedback on the diagram. At least, I wasn't able to figure out how.

Is there a way to do this, other than requiring students to download their diagram as an image file, import that file into an Google Drive text document and to have them share that file with their teacher?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's great to know that this issue is being worked on!

Comment: Indeed a missing feature

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any Drive commenting functionality currently built-in into draw.io, so setting to comment only won't do anything.

In terms of adding a diagram to a Google Doc, the [draw.io Add-on For Google Docs](https://support.draw.io/display/DAFGD/draw.io+Add-on+for+Google+Docs) makes that eay.